Several LNK2019 and LNK2001 "unresolved external symbol" errors when compiling modular UE5 C++ source code
I am attempting to build the solution of my Unreal Engine 5 project which consists of several code modules, two of which are CelBody and OrbitSuite. These modules are structured as Epic Games recommends (with private and public folders containing .cpp and .h files, respectively). OrbitSuite is a private dependency  of CelBody as it contains a data structure called FBodyData which is the type of one of the ACelBody actor class' member attributes.
The OrbitSuite and CelBody module folders inhabit the same source directory of my Unreal project and #includes are spelled correctly and IntelliSense shows zero issues regarding missing headers or unresolved members. In CelBody.Build.cs, OrbitSuite is included in the PrivateDependencyModuleNames string list which is unedited since the last time the project compiled successfully.
When I attempt to compile, the LNK2019 error reads:
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl FBodyData::FBodyData(void)" (??0FBodyData@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ACelBody::ACelBody(class FVTableHelper &)" (??0ACelBody@@QEAA@AEAVFVTableHelper@@@Z)

Looking up the error code, it apparently signals "when a declaration exists in a header file, but no matching definition is implemented" and, in this case, is referring to FBodyData's default constructor as it is called by the declaration of member FBodyData BodyData in the class definition of ACelBody. I've quadruple checked BodyData.h and BodyData.cpp and the default constructor is defined and implemented correctly.
I'd expect the compiler to have no issue locating the implementation of FBodyData() and fear the error may be caused by something unrelated. Let me know if there are logs it would be helpful to provide or if any more detail is required regarding file structure or class implementation.

This question is similar to: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no reason for this error other than 'when a declaration exists in a header file, but no matching definition is implemented'. You need to be more persistent in figuring out why this is happening. The error is most likely in your build practices, probably so that the file containing the definition is not getting compiled or not getting linked with the rest of your code.

As you didn't provide any code I can only guess, but you likely forgot to export your classes to use them in another module.
// <ModuleName>_API is defined as platform-specific DLL export/import 
// directives by UBT.
class CELBODY_API FBodyData
{
    FBodyData() = default;
};


Thank you so much, this was it. For some reason I thought _API was only necessary for UCLASSes (OrbitSuite consists of all USTRUCTs and UENUMs). Glad to know what that line means and sorry to everyone for not providing enough info.
